# Write a method for calculate average temp

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that returns the average temperature.
But I get the following error message:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <23.0> but was: <0.0>

What's wrong?

```
public class TempBewerking {

    public static double calculateTempAverage(double [] temp)
    {
        temp = new double [7];
        double tempAverage =0;

        
        for (int a = 0; a<temp.length;a++)
            tempAverage+=temp[a];
        
        tempAverage=tempAverage/temp.length;
        
        return tempAverage;
}
}
```

Comment: Delete this line: `temp = new double [7];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's normal cause you are reassigning the temp Array. temp = new double [7];

Comment: Not overriding, but reassigning. Variables cannot be overridden :)

Comment: that's true. nice catch